# How to execute Oracle utility in MSBuild

Tags: oracle, msbuild, msbuild-task

I want to execute the oracle's import utility in MSBuild as a task. Please give a detailed answer. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [MSBuild Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx).  I am not familiar with the Oracle utility you specified, but I do know that the Exec task will run most anything that can be run from a command line.  The relevant MSBuild configuration you would need might looks something like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="DoImport">
        <Exec 
            Command="imp SYSTEM/password FILE=dba.dmp FROMUSER=scott TABLES=(dept,emp)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat more long-winded but better solution is to develop a custom Task that extends the [ToolTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask.aspx) base class. This will allow better logging and you can define the arguments by using specific XML attributes.

I've developed one for SqlPlus and it works really well.